# didSelectRowAtIndexPath works incorrect with search results

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Before the search results, my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` works perfectly:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("fromContactsToChat", sender: OneRoster.userFromRosterAtIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath))
}
```

but when I search something and tap on the result, it sees my contact as old tableView cell indexPath. For example:

At first my tableView looks like:

```
Third User
First User
Second User
```

When I'm searching for `First` it shows me

```
First User
```

but when I tap on it, it see my `First User` as `Third User` from my old table, so there

```
OneRoster.userFromRosterAtIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath))
```

I got `Third User` credentials. How can I update it and fix? That when I click on the cell from my Search display it will open exactly for this searched contact.

If you have any questions, ask me, please

**UPDATE**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> onlineUserCell {
    let cell:onlineUserCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! onlineUserCell
    var us : User

    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
        us = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]
        cell.username.text = us.name
        cell.avatarImage.image = us.image

        tableView.rowHeight = 60
        cell.avatarImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.avatarImage.frame.size.height / 2
        cell.avatarImage.clipsToBounds = true
    } else {
        let user = OneRoster.userFromRosterAtIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath)
        let photoData = OneChat.sharedInstance.xmppvCardAvatarModule?.photoDataForJID(user.jid)

        cell.greenIndicator.alpha = 1
        if user.isOnline() {
            cell.greenIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        } else {
            cell.greenIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            // here here
        }

        cell.username.text = user.displayName
        configurePhotoForCell(cell, user: user)

        cell.avatarImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.avatarImage.frame.size.height / 2
        cell.avatarImage.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    return cell
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
struct User {
    let name : String
    let image: UIImage
}
```

**UPDATE 3**

```
public class func userFromRosterAtIndexPath(indexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject {
    return sharedInstance.fetchedResultsController()!.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject
}
```

Comment: I believe you 'see' the data in viewDidLoad, try to move the logic to viewDidAppear, this should solve your issue.

Comment: but I populate my tableView in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` @Greg

Comment: Can you post the code for cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: @Johnykutty sure! Done!

Comment: can you post `userFromRosterAtIndexPath` method code here

Comment: @PratyushaTerli please, look at update 3

Answer (score 2):

Your didselectRowAtIndexPath implementation should be like

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("fromContactsToChat", sender: filteredUsers[indexPath.row])
    }
    else {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("fromContactsToChat", sender: OneRoster.userFromRosterAtIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath))
    }
}
```

You are using your original datasource even in search results, thats the problem

Comment: Sorry, I did not talked about my struct. Please, look at my question, Update 2. So, before this I used `var us : User` this line inside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. When I used your code and paste `var us` out `cellForRowAtIndex` I got 2 errors: `Class 'ContactListTableViewController' has no initializers` and `Cannot convert value of type 'User' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'`

Comment: Now I get this: `Cannot subscript a value of type '[User]'` on line: `performSegueWithIdentifier("fromContactsToChat", sender: filteredUsers[indexPath.row])`

Comment: I just copied that line from your 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' if you gets error in 'didSelectRowAtIndexpath', you will get it in 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' also

Comment: because there I use `var us : User` and `us = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]`

Comment: you should use same data in your cellforrowatindexpath in your didselectrowatindexoath